# Setting a record's value to a variable in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, variables

I have a table with records in sqlite, and i want to assign the record's value to a variable, i tried this way:

```
latitudeB = database.execSQL("SELECT latitude FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE _id in (SELECT COUNT(_id)-1 FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")");
```

but execsql returns void. The sql code seems to work in sqlite

Comment: oh, i forgot to add: latitudeB is a double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `execSQL()` that is designated for statements which are not `SELECT`

So exactly from reference.

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.

instead it you need to use [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

```
String query = SELECT latitude FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
               + " WHERE _id in (SELECT COUNT(_id)-1 FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) { // if cursor is not empty
   // do your work
   double latitude = c.getDouble(0); // getting latitude's value
}
```